# Magento Tax Setting

Tags: magento

We are running a import/export business on Magento, we currently sales products among Australia, New Zealand and China.

Here is some tax issues confused us.

All the products either from Aus or NZ, the buyers actually from three different destinations, which is Australia, New Zealand and China. As China only play the role of buying, there are no products will flow out China to Australia and NZ.

There is Goods and Service tax (GST) in Aus and NZ with 10% and 15% respectively. However, Australia does NOT have GST on certain products, such as baby foods etc. NZ apply GST on everything.

OK, here are the cases: We need Magento tax to set like this:

If buyers locate in NZ and buy an Aus products, we need to charge 15% GST. 
If buyers locate in Aus and buy a NZ products, we need to charge the tax based on the type of the products, neither 10% nor nil
If buyers locate in China, doesn't matter what products he buy there will be GST charge.

Please....How to set the Tax rules in Magento?? Really confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create 2 separate tax rules for AUS and NZ under **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates > Add New Tax Rate**

   New Zealand Tax Rule

   [image: New Zealand Tax Rule]

   Australia Tax Rule

   [image: Australia Tax Rule]
2. Create two separate Product Tax Classes under **Sales > Tax > Product Tax Classes**.

   Create one named **Taxable Goods**.  This will be used to apply **both NZ and AUS** tax to products.

   Create one named **Taxable Goods - Excl AUS**.  This will be used to only apply **only NZ tax** to products.
3. Now create two Tax Rules under **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules**.

   The first tax rule should include both **NZ and AUS Tax Rates**.

   [image: NZ and AUS Rule]

   The second tax rule should include **JUST the NZ Tax Rate**.

   [image: NZ Rule]
4. Now go to your products and assign the Product Tax Classes.  On the Prices tab on the product edit page, look for the Tax Class field.

   Set it to **Taxable Goods** to charge both NZ and AUS tax.

   Set it to **Taxable Goods - Excl AUS** if the product is to exclude AUS tax (this is based on the product type)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works now.....But also need to confirm is the default price we entered as admin has to be a no-gst price?

Comment: because if the Chinese buyer, there will be no gst at all. How will make that happen?

Comment: You enter the price **without tax** (GST), and let the tax rules calculate and add on the tax during checkout.  If my answer worked for you, please be sure to accept it!